# Vim with Ack and "Silver searcher" - can not open file from result panel

Tags: vim, ack, ag

I am on Windows and use git-bash. I have vim (the default one that comes with git-bash) with several plugins installed via vim-plug.

When I use `:Ag ...` to search through the files in a project - I get this result panel:

[image: Results panel in Vim + Silver searcher]

But no matter what I try - I can't open the file with the result I want.

What should be the correct key shortcut(s) or combination so that I can open the file with the result I want?

EDIT:

This is what I added in my `~/.vimrc` file in order to make `:Ag` command work:

```
" Ag/Ack related ..
let g:ackprg = 'ag'
let g:ack_default_options = " --case-sensitive --noheading --nopager --nocolor --nogroup --column"
```

So probably the issue is related to some of these props?

Comment: The entries in the quickfix list appear to be malformed: no filename, no line number… which would explain why Vim can't open them. As to why… maybe your `ag` is broken or too old, maybe the plugin has trouble parsing its output… You should probably use the plugin's issue tracker to figure it all with the maintainer. FWIW, it is *very* easy to use `ag` in Vim without a plugin.

Comment: @romainl - I updated my question with the info I added to my `~/.vimrc` file - I forgot to mention that, my bad. ... But also - how do you use `ag` in vim without a plugin? ... I have the command globally available - but I thought I need a plugin in vim in order to use it ...

Comment: The plugin's issue tracker is a better place for this question. For using `ag` in Vim, see `:help 'grepprg'`.

Comment: FWIW, the recommended option to pass to `ag` from Vim is `--vimgrep`, which makes `--noheading`, `--nopager`, `--nocolor`, `--nogroup`, and `--column` redundant.